# How can I run my electron project from Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, electron

I'm new in JavaScript. And I want to create an application with electron framework in Visual Studio Code.
I'm working on debian. The electron module is installed locally, and I can execute my app from command line. But unfortunately I can't set up the VS code to run it. I tried this [guide](http://www.mylifeforthecode.com/a-better-way-to-launch-electron-from-visual-studio-code/), but it didn't help me.
I have the following launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
// List of configurations. Add new configurations or edit existing ones.
// ONLY "node" and "mono" are supported, change "type" to switch.
"configurations": [
    {
        // Name of configuration; appears in the launch configuration drop down menu.
        "name": "Launch main.js",
        // Type of configuration. Possible values: "node", "mono".
        "type": "node",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the program.
        "program": "electron/main.js",
        // Automatically stop program after launch.
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        // Command line arguments passed to the program.
        "args": [],
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the working directory of the program being debugged. Default is the current workspace.
        "cwd": ".",
        // Workspace relative or absolute path to the runtime executable to be used. Default is the runtime executable on the PATH.
        "runtimeExecutable": "node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/electron",
        // Optional arguments passed to the runtime executable.
        "runtimeArgs": [],
        // Environment variables passed to the program.
        "env": {
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        // Use JavaScript source maps (if they exist).
        "sourceMaps": false,
        // If JavaScript source maps are enabled, the generated code is expected in this directory.
        "outDir": null
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach",
        "type": "node",
        // TCP/IP address. Default is "localhost".
        "address": "localhost",
        // Port to attach to.
        "port": 5858,
        "sourceMaps": false
    }
]
```

}

If I try to execute, but a blank terminal comes up and the VS code says that "OpenDebug process has terminated unexpectedly".

### Update:

Meanwhile Visual Studio Code has been improved a lot. Here is a good description, how should be VS code set up for electron:
http://electron.rocks/debugging-electron-in-vs-code/

Answer (score 0):

When you run electron like that you need to pass an argument to the directory containing your app. There may be some other issue but I think you need to set the program to be the local directory instead of a file:

```
"program": ".",
```

Code should then invoke the electron script and pass `"."` as the first argument now. It could be that the debug options aren't supported by electron also, try unsetting the port and address properties.